# "Import" Polymer elements in a js file

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web, polymer

at the moment i am working at a webapp using a custom framework and i am trying to implement polymer web elements. 
There is no html, except for the index.html and contents, and everything else is created using javascript. Also, the created content is (at the moment) placed in a dedicated iframe (cough) and is either a .html file or a created *something* with js.
So my question is - can i just "Insert" a polymer element?.

At one point there is a map.js which, when called by a other script, creates a google map - can i write a script which creates a  polymer, preferably working in an iframe?
And places it somewhere?

Maybe i am overlooking some awesome polymer magic or javascript technique.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually _import_ means _load the definition_, but it sounds like you are talking about making instances. You can create a Polymer element in JavaScript like any other element, e.g. `document.createElement('tag-name')`. Please clarify if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hi, we ditched the old framework in favor of polymer. I wanted to create  a polymer element in js without using html files. Or, on a different note, use html files but implementing it dynamically with js.
But, as said, we ditched the old framework for some shiny web awesomeness :)